# Finding user control in TemplateField of DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, detailsview, findcontrol

I have a DetailsView that I'm posting back - and inside of that is a UserControl. I'm having some difficulty located it in the postback data.

As an example:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvDetailsView" runat="Server" AutoGenerateRows="false">
<Fields>
  <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      Some text here
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <uc:UserControl ID="ucUserControl" runat="server" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
      <uc:UserControl ID="ucUserControl" runat="server" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

When I postback, I would assume I would do something like this:

```
MyUserControlType ucUserControl = dvDetailsView.FindControl("ucUserControl") as MyUserControlType;
```

But this finds nothing. In fact, I can't even find this baby by walking around in QuickWatch...

What do I need to do to find this thing??

**EDIT:** It turns out my usercontrol id was being changed - but why? I do have the same ID on both the insert and edit templates, but commenting that out made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the user control name was changed - my usercontrol, labelled as "ucUserControl" had it's name changed to a generic name - 'ctl01'.

So, doing a`dvSituation.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("ctl01")` found the control.

To find this ID, I just had a look at the HTML element being rendered, and checked the parent from the id, e.g. '`ctl00_MainContent_dvDetailsView_ctl01_lblLabel`', where lblLabel appeared on ucUserControl.

The rows column is a 0 based index of the number of fields, and the cells index will be 1 if you have a headertemplate specified.

**EDIT**: OMG! Someone (it really wasn't me, I swear) had hidden the ID property on the control class!

```
public partial class UserControl : BaseControl
{
  public int Id;
}
```

This meant that when ASP.Net was generating the id, it couldn't, and just assigned a generic Id ('ctl01' in this case) to the control, rather than the actual name.

Wow.

Answer (score 2):

**After** `DataBind`ing the control, you'd use:

```
dvDetailsView.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("ucUserControl")
```

And make sure you are doing this only in Edit mode as the control only exists in `EditItemTemplate`.

Comment: Still can't find this control, although I have another that I can find (it's just an `<asp:TextBox>` control.

Comment: Are you sure your details view is in edit mode, and you are doing it after DataBinding? I just tested and this worked. Check `CurrentMode` property to see if you are really in edit mode.

Comment: No row should exist before data binding. Let alone child controls.