# DropDownList insideTemplateField is not accessible from code-behind

Tags: asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu, templatefield

i am updating my table by placing datailsview in the webpage and giving it a datasource,

i have introduced a dropdownlist in the middle of bounded control and want it to be filled
according to my given instruction, but the DropDownList is not accessible via ID in code-behind, e.g.:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdownlist" DataSourceID="deptsource" Width="150px" DataTextField="deptname" DataValueField="deptid" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: From what code-behind event handler are your trying to access your DropDownList? And how?

Comment: i want to directly access dropdownlist in page_Load event handler.

Comment: Directly? You can't. You have to `DropDownList list = (DropDownList)details.FindControl("dropDownList1");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to use the `FindControl()` method after rows are databound as abatishchev mentioned. Also, you need to remember that this wont be possible until there are in fact some rows in the grid. But you need to also remember that you will not get just one `DropDownList`, but instead there will be one `DropDownList` for each row in your `GridView`.

Answer (score 0):

See

- [Finding user control in TemplateField of DetailsView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881416/finding-usercontrol-in-templatefield-detailsview)
- [How to find control in TemplateField of GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873973/how-to-find-control-in-gridview-template-field)
- [FormView.FindControl() returns null until DataBind()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171427/formview-findcontrol-returns-null-until-databind)

and [many similar](https://www.google.com/search?q=findcontrol%20TemplateField%20site:stackoverflow.com).

Call `FindControl()` after data-binding occurs.