# find label in details view which is inside login view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I able to find DetailsView inside LoginView1

```
DetailsView DetailsView1 = (DetailsView)LoginView1.FindControl("DetailsView1");
```

Above statement works...
But I fail to find label inside DetailsView

```
Label id = (Label)DetailsView1.FindControl("id");
```

the above statement return me null

here my aspx code

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
        <LoggedInTemplate>
            <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
                DataKeyNames="FeeID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" 
                Visible="False" Width="100%">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FeeID" InsertVisible="False" 
                        SortExpression="FeeID">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FeeID")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="id" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FeeID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
        </Fields>
                    </asp:DetailsView>
        </LoggedInTemplate>
            <AnonymousTemplate>
            Access Denied.
            </AnonymousTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: We would need to see the markup.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Finding user control in TemplateField of DetailsView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881416/finding-user-control-in-templatefield-of-detailsview)

Answer (score 0):

After DataBinding the control, you'd use:

```
DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("id")
```

Try , it might work or change the row or cell index accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> First,

```
DetailsView view = (DetailsView)LoginView1.Rows[0].FindControl("DetailsView1");
```

> Then,

```
Label id = (Label)view.rows[0].FindControl("id");
```